# Android Не запускается Service

Tags: android, service

В активности вызываю сервис

```
PendingIntent pi;
            Intent intent;
            Intent intent_empty = new Intent();
            // Создаем PendingIntent
            pi = createPendingResult(1 ,intent_empty, 0);
            // Создаем Intent для вызова сервиса
            // и созданный PendingIntent
            intent = new Intent(this, VideoService.class).putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi).putExtra(PARAM_FLAG, false);
            // стартуем сервис
            startService(intent);
```

Он не запускается. Вообще. Код сервиса:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    System.out.println("onStartCommand");
  }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    System.out.println("onStartCommand");

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

    boolean flag = intent.getBooleanExtra(VideoR.PARAM_FLAG, false);
    PendingIntent pi = intent.getParcelableExtra(VideoR.PARAM_PINTENT);

    if (!flag) {
        startRecord(pi);
    }
    else {
        stopRecord(pi);
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
  }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: откуда знаешь что не запускается?

Comment: Потому что System.out.println ничего не выводит. При нажатии кнопки также ничего не происходит.

Comment: мне кажется ты забыл его в манифесте объявить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держи готовый сервис.

```
 public class MyService extends Service {
            MediaPlayer player;

            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg);
                player.setLooping(true); // зацикливаем
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                player.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                player.start();
            }
    }
```

Далее нам нужно его зарегистрировать в AndroidManifest'e.xml как и активити, для того что бы Eclipse знал что этот класс можно запускать как сервис:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
```

А дальше мы запускаем наш сервис из активности:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Ну и в нужном месте мы его будем останавливать, например по нажатию кнопки:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Comment: Точно! Я забыл в манифесте объявить сервис. Спасибо огромное за ответ!